# Refresh First Page after Modal Bottom Sheet is closed

Tags: flutter

So i have a screen on which there is a button which opens a full screen modal bottom sheet
And a user selects a option from that modal sheet then it closes and then i have to display the option on screen 1 which was behind modal sheet but i can't get it to do that

Screen 1(Click on Button) > Modal Sheet (Select a Option) > Close Modal Sheet > Screen 1 (Display the selected option)

I have a pop function which closes the modal sheet and then a push replacement function which replaces the Screen 1 with Screen 1 but the Screen 1 doesn't update

Button user clicks -

```dart
InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            if (locDenied) {
              var status = await Permission.location.status;

              if (status.isDenied) {
                openAppSettings();
              }
            } else {
              Future<List<Placemark>> placemarks = getLocation();

              placemarks.then((value) => {
                    selectedLocation = {
                      'state': value.first.administrativeArea,
                      'city': value.first.locality,
                      'allIndia': false
                    }
                  });
              LocText = 'Fetching Location...';

              Navigator.pop(context);

              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                PageRouteBuilder(
                    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => MainApp(),
                    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                    transitionsBuilder:
                        (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                      const begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
                      const end = Offset.zero;

                      final tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end);
                      final offsetAnimation = animation.drive(tween);

                      return SlideTransition(
                        position: offsetAnimation,
                        child: child,
                      );
                    }),
              );
            }
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 55,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border:
                      Border.all(color: Colors.deepPurple.shade500, width: 2)),
              child: Center(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.my_location,
                      color: Colors.deepPurple.shade500,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Use Current Location',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepPurple.shade500, fontSize: 20),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        locDenied
                            ? Text('No Location Permission')
                            : Text(LocText),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code to the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things you have you do

1. Create a variable to handle a result of choice in **modalBottomSheet**

   ```
   final result = await showModalBottomSheet<String>(...);
   ```
2. In the bottom sheet item you need to call the pop method with the result

   ```
   Navigator.pop(context, 'First Item');
   ```
3. Check the result for null and add it to state variable

   ```
   if (result != null) {
    setState(() {
     _choice = result;
    });
   }
   ```

The **result** will be null if case when a user closes the bottom sheet with no choice (using swap or something else)

And finally, this is a full example. Enjoy

```
class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  String _choice = 'Nothing';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('First Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Choise: $_choice',
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final result = await showModalBottomSheet<String>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          title: const Text('First Item'),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context, 'First Item');
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: const Text('Second Item'),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context, 'Second Item');
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: const Text('Third Item'),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context, 'Third Item');
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
                if (result != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    _choice = result;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Select something'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```